# Unable to run bare Expo project due to LogBox error

Tags: react-native, expo

I am getting the following error after I create an Expo project and try to run it (I am using npx create-expo-app some-name, cd some-name, run on android device):

```
Android Bundling failed 21504ms
error: node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\UI\LogBoxImages\close.png: assetUrlPath.replaceAll is not a function
```

I haven't done anything with the code yet - I am simply trying to create a bare expo project and run it. I have previously been able to create Expo projects and run them without problems, but I haven't used my computer for about a month.

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled node js, and it works again.

Answer (score 0):

i've just encountered the same problem and this what i did to fix it :

- delete node_modules folder
- clean the cache by **yarn cache clean --force** or **npm cache clean --force**
- then run **yarn install** or **npm install**

and happy coding :)